# OpenSSH won't resolve %temp% environment variable in commands and batch files

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, environment-variables, windows-server-2012-r2

I installed OpenSSH on my Windows Server 2012 R2 system. So far everything works except for resolving the `%temp%` environment variable:

[image: Environment variable problem on PuTTy]

In my PuTTy SSH client I can resolve `%systemroot%` but not `%temp%`, on the cmd on my server, I can use both.

In the environment variable settings I won't locate the correct TEMP variable, as all entries will point to a different directory:

[image: Environment variable settings]

So how can I allow SSH to resolve this environment variable?